# Work of a penetration tester?

Tags: penetration-testing

I'm interested in a job involving security and I was curios what its like as a pen tester from the time the client approches you to the time your finished.

Like what steps are taken to test an app?

Comment: If you have to ask, than you're by far not ready for the work ;)
For the rest, try wikipedia as a starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_tester
Short version though... find out what software they are running, see if there are any known vulnerabilities. If not, try and find some yourself.

Comment: well im not putting in my resumé tomorrow, im just intrested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the penetration testing standard in order:

-[Pre-engagement Interactions](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Pre-engagement)
-[Intelligence Gathering](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Intelligence_Gathering)
-[Threat Modeling](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Threat_Modeling)
-[Vulnerability Analysis](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Vulnerability_Analysis)
-[Exploitation](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Exploitation)
-[Post Exploitation](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Post_Exploitation)
-[Reporting](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Reporting)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the application itself but in general there is standard for a complete penetration testing :

[Penetration testing standard](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Main_Page)

but for me it depend more on the Penetration tester himself , you need to practice then have your own personality in the Penetration testing , you may use some tools like :

- vulnerability scanners
- network scanners
- reverse engineering tools
- .....